# Which components grow in size but not in number and which grow in number but not in size?

Tags: human-physiology

During growth of an individual animal some components of the body grow in size but not in number (type 1) while some others increase in number but not in size (type 2). Which of the following is correct? 
(A) type 1: bones and muscle cells; type 2: hair follicles, red blood cells and epithelial cells. 
(B) type 1: bones and red blood cells; type 2: hair follicles, muscle cells and epithelial cells. 
(C) type 1: hair follicles and muscle cells; type 2: bones, red blood cells and epithelial cells. 
(D) type 1: epithelial cells and bones; type 2: hair follicles, red blood cells and muscle cells.

I know muscle cells only grow in size. I am unsure about hair follicles, which is why I am confused between options A and C. I am also confused about bone growth. Does it ever increase in number? It would be nice if someone could clear that up. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Did you ever see giant hair follicles in adults? :)

Comment: I'll admit I didn't think of it that way. So do they increase in number then? And what about bones?

Comment: Well, either they grow in number, or, if they stay the same size, they become less and less dense when we grow up. Which option do you think is the correct one? Also, have a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteocyte). Can you tell something about bone cell growth?

Comment: (It's not that I don't want to give you the correct answer straight away; it's just, you know: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.")

Comment: Clearly they become less and less dense, duh. Also a new bone would require more osteoblasts and since they don't divide, bones don't grow in number? I like that you want to me to learn to think for myself but you pretty much gave away the answers. :D So bones, muscle cells and hair follicles don't grow in number? None of the options are correct in that case.

Comment: No, come on, if they become less dense we would have the same number of hair as babies and as 2 metres tall individuals, and it seems unlikely to me that a basketball player and a newborn baby have the same number of hair, isn't it?

Comment: This means that the number of hairs you had on your head when you were born and now is the same. I don't think so, right?

Comment: You're right. I got confused. I'm not thinking straight. They grow in number. I think that solved my question. Answer should be A. Thank you for being so patient. You're a good teacher. :)

Comment: You're welcome, Fenil. Remember: common sense before biology ;)

Comment: I posted an answer summarizing the process we underwent to get a solution, so that you can upvote and accept it and the question can be regarded as solved :D

Comment: I am not sure if I can upvote. The +1 seems to go away after a bit. I think it's because I don't have enough reputation. This feels like a dystopia movie. Not complaining, though.

Comment: Strange, according to [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) you should be able to upvote answers on your own questions... Well, surely you have the privilege of accepting the answer by marking the tick sign at the left of the answer. :)

Comment: Done. BTW, is there any chance I can talk to you properly somewhere? I don't have anything in particular to ask. I would just like to get to know you a bit, since I plan to pursue to biology in college as well and probably head into research.

Comment: Sure! We can talk in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) here. You still don't have enough reputation to talk there; I'll proceed and up vote two of your question so that you gain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We navigated through this question with Fenil in comments, I'll resume the answer here:

## Osteocytes

We know from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteocyte) that "osteocytes have an average half life of 25 years, they do not divide" and that "when osteoblasts become trapped in the matrix that they secrete, they become osteocytes. Osteocytes are networked to each other via long cytoplasmic extensions that occupy tiny canals called canaliculi".

We can thus conclude that bone cells don't grow in numbers, but in size by their cytoplasmic extensions.

## Hair follicles

Well, we draw the conclusion that hair follicles grow in number and not in size based on the following common sense observations:

- We don't get to see tiny hair follicles in babies and giant ones in adults;
- If they don't grow in size, either they grow in number or they become less and less dense as the skin surface grows with age. If the latter, we should see the same hair number in babies and in adults, whichever their height is, and this is obviously not the case.

So, they grow in number.

The answer is $A$.